# как отключить message_handler aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

я хочу получить данные от пользователя но код дойдя до получения возраста начинает запрашивать возраст бесконечно

```
import data
import keyboards as btn
import io
from aiogram import types ,Dispatcher , Bot ,executor 

bot = Bot("TOKEN")

dis = Dispatcher(bot)

@dis.message_handler(commands=["register"])
async def register(msg : types.Message):

user =data.getUserid(msg.from_user.id)
await msg.answer("введите ваше имя")
async def innerName(inMsg : types.Message ):
    if user is None:
        name = inMsg.text
    else:
        user.name = inMsg.text
    async def innerAge(inMsg : types.Message ):
        if user is None:
            age = inMsg.text
        else:
            user.age = inMsg.text
            await msg.answer(f"name: {name} ; age : {age}")

    await msg.answer("введите ваш возраст")
    dis.register_message_handler(innerAge) 
dis.register_message_handler(innerName)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dis,skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь с [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html)